how to set connection timeout on remote firebird?
With my Xamarin Forms app I connect to a Firebird database on my Windows PC when I'm on the same WiFi network by the IP address. This is the connection string:
@"Server=" + ipaddress + @";User=sysdba;Password=xxxxxxxx;Pooling=false;Connection timeout=2;Database=" + ipaddress + @":C:\FirebirdSQL\Photo.FDB;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Packet Size=32767;FbServerType.Embedded;";

Everything works correctly if I enter the right IP address, but if I enter a non-existent IP address the connection loops for 2 minutes from the moment it opens and then reports that it is impossible to connect to that IP address. How can I intervene on the timeout period for invalid connection?
I tried changing the ConnectionTimeout time to 2 seconds in firebird.conf but it has no effect. Maybe because the request comes from an Android app?

Not related to your problem, but the presence of FbServerType.Embedded; in your connection string makes zero sense: 1) you're trying to create a network connection (and thus not using Firebird embedded), and 2) if you wanted to use Firebird embedded, you need to specify the ServerType property.

The ConnectionTimeout setting in firebird.conf is irrelevant, because that only governs connections that are made with the fbclient.dll in the same directory as the configuration file (e.g. the server acting as a client connecting to other servers). In your case, you're using the Firebird ADO.net provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient), which 1) doesn't use fbclient.dll, and 2) is on a different system, so even if it did, the setting on the server would not affect your client.
The Connection timeout property you set in your connection string is not used for controlling the timeout of the connection when you use plain Open() on the FbConnection. You need to use OpenAsync(...) for it to take effect. You don't actually show code in your question, but I guess you're not using the async variant.

I also tried using await conn.OpenAsync() and await conn.CloseAsync() but the only effect obtained is that the thread does not block but the incorrect connection message still occurs after 2 minutes.

I rewrote the code using stringbuilder and saw the possibilities of configuring the server. I used FbServerType.Default; with the asynchronous connection and everything seems to work. I'll do some more tests this evening but it seems ok to me. Thank you. I will mark your answer as valid. Thank you. Here is my code

This is the code I used to solve the problem:
private async void ceck_connection()
{         
    try          
        {
        isconnected = false;
        btndownload.Source = "downloadr";
        string ipp="";

        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("ip"))
        {
        string[] st = Application.Current.Properties["ip"].ToString().Split(new char[] { 'ò' });
        ipp = st[0];
        
        }
                  
        FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        cs.Password = "xxxxxxxx";
        cs.Database = ipp + @":C:\FirebirdSQL\Photo.FDB";
        cs.Charset = "UTF8";
        cs.Pooling = false;
        cs.Dialect = 3;
        cs.PacketSize= 32767;
        cs.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
        FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(cs.ToString());         
        await  conn.OpenAsync();
        await conn.CloseAsync();       

        isconnected = true;
        btndownload.Source = "downloadw";
      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isconnected = false;
        btndownload.Source = "downloadr";
        await DisplayAlert("", ex.Message, "Conjtinua");
    }

}

